# Header Manager and Recording Controller

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

In my test scripts, I use a header manager that is shared at a thread group level, and then each sampler has it's own header as well for things that change (referrer, certain pragmas and cache-control) from request to request. I do this for ease of control e.g. so I can easily change the user agent for all requests.

I use the proxy and a recording controller to make the majority of my scripts, and I have set a header manager as a child of the recording controller - I have also tested this by setting a header manager inside the proxy element, but neither of these work as I want.

What it is doing is adding in a full set of headers from the browser, and not just those missing or different than what I have specified in the header manager.

Am I missing something, or is there even a way to do what I am trying to do?

I am using jmeter 2.6.

Comment: It's not clear from your question where the issue is. Recording and playback are separate, which one is your problem with?

Comment: My problem is that the recording controller is recording a full set of headers, despite the use of a header manager. What I want it to do is only record the headers that are different - like the way it will only record the HTTP sampler fields that differ from a HTTP Request Default.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The header manager is for playback and I'm pretty sure you can't use it as part of recording. But then, I also think that the HTTP Request Default control is for playback and that it would have no affect on recording, but you're saying it does, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I know at least in 2.6, if you use the HTTP Request Defaults under the Recording Controller, it will leave the sampler fields blank if they are filled out in the defaults controller. I did write a java app to strip them out as an interim work around, but I am hoping to find a solution just in jmeter - though it may not be possible at this point, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this doesn't happen yet in Jmeter. I am using 2.7 and see the same behavior.

I believe the original intent of the HTTP Request Defaults and HTTP Header Manager was to ease the task of developers creating scripts by hand. With the increased usage of the HTTP Proxy Controller, the application of the the above two elements needs to be extended to the Proxy Controller as well for recording.